# Safari Extension Icon Become Very Small in macOS 12.3

Tags: icons, safari-extension

The icon size was fine on previous version of macOS. After installed macOS 12.3, the icon became very small. The icon I used was 34x34 in pixel. I tried to use large icon, size 256x256 in pixel. However, the icon was still small. My code:

```swift
override func validateToolbarItem(in window: SFSafariWindow, validationHandler: @escaping ((Bool, String) -> Void)) {
    // This is called when Safari's state changed in some way that would require the extension's toolbar item to be validated again.

    window.getToolbarItem { (toolbarItem) in
        toolbarItem?.setImage(NSImage(named: "MonochromeIcon"))
        toolbarItem?.setLabel(NSLocalizedString("Open URL in Page By Poster 2", comment: ""))
    }
    
    validationHandler(true, "")
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was the issue of Safari itself. I tried to used another icon and everything was fine. So only the icon I used can't be used.

For workaround, I had to change the icon. I will file a bug report to Apple and let them to investigate.

----Update-----

To use my original icon, I reimplemented the macOS Safari extension. Currently, macOS Safari extension could be implemented the same as iOS extension. And in that way, the icon will work.